# Dynamically add title to checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I am trying to add a title to checkbox dynamically and I cannot put all sentence to it. I need to explain user why the check box is not available.

I use this part of code.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="RNb" value=@item.ReportNbr @{ @(item.ResultTp == "T4" ? null : new { disabled = "disabled" })  } @{ @(item.ResultTp == "T4" ? null : new { title = "No Data available" })  } />
```

The checkbox works properly, but title displays only the first word 'No'.
I tried to insert `&nbsp;` but it does not help. It displays any character except 'space'.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In your controller can you use `ViewBag.CheckboxTitle` to set the title of the checkbox?

Comment: Can u get the text as model property?

Comment: I do not want to use ViewBag. Actually this is a list of check boxes that represent list of records from database and depends on status I need to disable required check boxes.

Comment: Model property produce same result as I have right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can rewrite setting your title attribute to something like this

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="RNb" value=@item.ReportNbr
       @{ @(item.ResultTp == "T4" ? null : new { disabled = "disabled" })    }
       title="@( item.ResultTp == "T4" ? "" : "No Data available")"
       />
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like only available option.